# ORACLE 12.2 - Invalid string conversion from CLOB fiel using JDBC THIN driver

Tags: oracle12c

we have ORACLE database in charset WIN1250 (EE8MSWIN1250). Until ORACLE version 12.1 was everything Ok. But now we have installed ORACLE 12.2 and same data which are read from database contains invalid characters. For example, i show screenshot from DBeaver (It is something like SQLDeveloper - but it universal and for connection to ORACLE have used same THIN driver as we) Firs two pictures are from ORACLE 12.1 (settings and data from table with CLOB field) and second two pictures are from ORACLE 12.2 (settings and same data)

Does anybody know what difference is between 12.1 and 12.2 version? I have read many documents on ORACLE website but no result.

ORACLE 12.1 SETTINGS

[image: ORACLE 12.1 SETTINGS]

Data from ORACLE 12.1 - correct characters

[image: Data from ORACLE 12.1]

ORACLE 12.2 SETTINGS

[image: ORACLE 12.2 SETTINGS]

Data from ORACLE 12.2 - contains invalid characters

[image: Data from ORACLE 12.2]

Comment: One difference is that 12.2 defaults to the UTF8 character set.  Is it possible that when someone installed 12.2 they accidentally used the new default, and then they converted it instead of re-installing it?  Converting the database character set is tricky and can easily corrupt data.

Comment: I don't think that this is reason. Oracle was installed and data were imported after installation. In case ORACLE 12.1 everything was Ok but in case ORACLE 12.2 data contains invalid characters.

Comment: Did you think to ask Oracle? I assume you have a service agreement?

Comment: Sure, we are SW developers and also we have Oracle as our database. I can try to ask Oracle, but their support process is so complicated :) . I hoped that somebody will know answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is issue in ORACLE 12cR2.  It is necessary to apply patch number 27002286.
For my case it was "Patch 27002286: WINDOWS DB BUNDLE PATCH 12.2.0.1.171130"

It will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Quite an older thread, but I think that we do have a similar problem ...

While (finally) upgrading from Oracle 11 to Oracle 12 we experience the same problems as described above.

Our Java-based application did well connecting to the Oracle 11 DB but with Oracle 12 some characters (especially in German e.g. ä,ü,ö) are corrupt when stored in CLOB fields.

Browsing the internet I haven't found anything that addresses this problem directly.

Do other people have or had the same problems and what is/was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by applying Patch 26380097 for Oracle DB 12.2.0.1 on Linux x86_64.
This is documented in [Oracle Doc ID 2377078](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2377078_1.html).